# Camel error thrown while working with interceptSendToEndpoint

Tags: apache-camel, interceptor

While working with the interceptSendToEndpoint, below route throws  **org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://result]. Exchange[Message: ]**

How could I resolve it? Thanks in advance.

```
public class SampleRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String expectedBody = "<matched/>";
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", expectedBody, "foo", "bar");
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:result").process(exchange -> System.out.println("intercepted"));
                from("direct:start").to("direct:result").process(exchange -> System.out.println("after"));

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a consumer on "direct:result", eg a route with

```
from("direct:result")
   .to("log:result")
```

Or something. Or instead of direct use a mock / seda or other component.

The direct component is for direct method invocation, eg there must be a link between to->from